# How to hit HTTP endpoint from Docker image?

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker

I have `NodeJS/TypeScript` application (github repo) which is working fine when I run the `script` defined in `package.json`. i.e., `npm run start` will start my local host and I can hit endpoint via POSTMAN.

I have created docker image (I am new to `Docker` and this is my first image). Here, I am getting `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7001` error in POSTMAN.

I noticed that I do not see `Listening on port 7001` message in terminal when I run docker file. This tells me that I am making some mistake in `.Dockerfile`.

**Steps:**

- I created docker image using `docker build -t <IMAGE-NAME> .` I can see successfully created image.
- I launched container using `docker run --name <CONTAINER-NAME> <IMAGE-NAME>`
- I've also disabled `Use the system proxy` setting in POSTMAN but no luck.

**Details:**

- **Package.json file**

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --pretty --transpile-only src/server.ts",
    "compile": "tsc -p .",
    "start": "npm run compile && npm run dev"
  }
```

- **Response from `terminal` when I run `npm run start`** (This is successful)

[image]

- **`Dockerfile`**

```
#FROM is the base image for which we will run our application
FROM node:12.0.0

# Copy source code
COPY . /app 

# Change working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g typescript

# Expose API port to the outside 
EXPOSE 7001

# Launch application
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

- **Response after running docker command**

[image]

- GitHub repo structure

[image]

Comment: The 'EXPOSE' command just lets docker know the port should be available in the container for access outside it.  To actually use it from outside docker you need to use '-p'  as Dante explains in his answer.  You may have a dozen web server containers all exposing the same port, but they could be mapped to different ports on the host.  [This post](https://we-are.bookmyshow.com/understanding-expose-in-dockerfile-266938b6a33d) does a good job of explaining it I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By any chance did you forget to map your container port to the host one?

`docker run --name <CONTAINER-NAME> -p 7001:7001 <IMAGE-NAME>`

the `-p` does the trick of exposing the port to your network. The number on the left side is the container port (7001 as exposed on the Dockerfile) and the second one is the target port on the host machine. You can set this up to  other available ports as well. Eg.: `-p 7001:3000`to expose on http://localhost:3000

Check out Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports) about networking

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I do not get that error anymore. I am seeing `socket hung up` error instead. Let me try to fix that. Looks like my express server is not running but this is my guess right now.

Comment: If that worked please mark as correct answer to help others find eeasily.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to make this work with two things:

1. Using @Dante's suggestion (mentioned above).
2. Updating my `.Dockerfile` with following:

```
FROM node:12.0.0

# Change working directory
WORKDIR /user/app

# Copy package.json into the container at /app
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g typescript

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at root level (in this case, /app directory)
COPY . ./

# Expose API port to the outside 
EXPOSE 7001

# Launch application
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```